# Python regex extract previous/next group from anchor point in string

Tags: python, regex

Given a string containing four values:

```
1) Vehicle model        <- any number of alpha-numeric words
2) Engine description   <- one word before the next value:
3) Power output         <- \d+KW
4) Optional keywords    <- any number of alpha-numeric words

For example:
1-SERIE 118I 105KW EFF.DYN. BUSINESS LINE
MINI CLUBMAN 1.6T 128KW COOPER S
TWINGO 1.2 55KW
```

How to extract these into Python variables using re?

I think the simplest approach is to first find the *power output* (an anchor point), and then match the previous word to find the *engine description*, and then match everything before that to retrieve the *model*. Also match everything after the power output to find the *optional keywords*.

I feel I need to do something with (?<= ..) but I can't get it to work..

Slightly modified from Matt G. (added named groups and matches all optional keywords):

```
^(?P<model>([\S\s]+?))(?= \S+(?= \d+KW)) (?P<engine>(\S+))(?=(?= \d+KW)) (?P<kw>(\d+))KW(?P<keywords>(?<=KW)\s?(.*))
```

Comment: Where that data comes from? Where did you get that?

Comment: Flat file. It's what I've to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `^([\S\s]+?)(?= \S+(?= \d+KW)) (\S+)(?=(?= \d+KW)) (\d+)KW(?: ([^\s]+))*`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QrCsQx/2)

Comment: Almost. It does not match all keywords after the engine output. but only the last one. Eg. "LINE", "S" in the examples

Comment: @svenema, try it in python code? regex101 might not show multiple matched groups..

Comment: This works: m = re.search("^(?P<model>([\S\s]+?))(?= \S+(?= \d+KW)) (?P<engine>(\S+))(?=(?= \d+KW)) (?P<kw>(\d+))KW(?P<keywords>(?<=KW)(.*))",edition_text,re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: @svenema, I assumed the requirement was to match each optional keyword separately..

Comment: That would be nice too (but not needed), however using your regexp only the last word is captured, both in reg101 and in Python.